# How do I make an if class do nothing if there is nothing written in the rectangle?

Tags: javascript, khan-academy

So I'm making Tic Tac Toe and I made it so that when I click on the empty rectangles (tiles) it puts the label X or O on the tile, but if the tile is labeled (not empty) I want the code to not write anything.

That's how the piece of code looks currently:

```
 if (!this.empty ()) {
        exit ();
    }
```

The issue is that when I press on a tile that is labeled the program stops entirely and I can no longer see a X or an O when clicking on an empty tile. Is there an alternative for exit(); that doesn't do that?

Here's the complete code (this code is actually not by me it's an practice from KhanAcademy):
https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming/programming-games-visualizations/memory-game/pc/challenge-tic-tac-toe

```
var playerTurn = 0;
var NUM_COLS = 3;
var NUM_ROWS = 3;
var SYMBOLS =["X","O"];
var tiles = [];

var checkWin = function() {

};

var Tile = function(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.size = width/NUM_COLS;
    this.label = "";
};

Tile.prototype.draw = function() {
    fill(214, 247, 202);
    strokeWeight(2);
    rect(this.x, this.y, this.size, this.size, 10);
    textSize(100);
    textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
    fill(0, 0, 0);
    text(this.label, this.x+this.size/2, this.y+this.size/2);
};

Tile.prototype.empty = function() {
    return this.label === "";
};

Tile.prototype.onClick = function() {
    // If the tile is not empty, exit the function
    if (!this.empty ()) {
        exit();
    }
    // Put the player's symbol on the tile

        this.label = SYMBOLS[playerTurn];

    // Change the turn
    playerTurn ++;
    if (playerTurn >= 1) {
        playerTurn = 0;
    }
};

Tile.prototype.handleMouseClick = function(x, y) {
    // Check for mouse clicks inside the tile
    if (x >= this.x && x <= this.x + this.size &&
    y >= this.y && y <= this.y + this.size)
    {
        this.onClick();
    }
};

for (var i = 0; i < NUM_COLS; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < NUM_ROWS; j++) {
        tiles.push(new Tile(i * (width/NUM_COLS-1), j * (height/NUM_ROWS-1)));
    }
}

var drawTiles = function() {
    for (var i in tiles) {
        tiles[i].draw();
    }
};

mouseReleased = function() {
    for (var i in tiles) {
        tiles[i].handleMouseClick(mouseX, mouseY);
    }
};

draw = function() {
    background(143, 143, 143);
    drawTiles();

};
```

Comment: If its just tic-tac-toe, can you please post your complete source? It would be helpful for those who you want to debug your issue.

Answer (score 0):

The function `exit` is not a native function to javascript.  It means nothing in this context as it has not been defined anywhere.  You can use the word `return` to end execution of a function - it does what I think you're trying to accomplish with `exit()`

```js
Tile.prototype.onClick = function() {
    // If the tile is not empty, exit the function
    if (!this.empty ()) {
        return
    } else {
    // Put the player's symbol on the tile

        this.label = SYMBOLS[playerTurn];

    // Change the turn

    playerTurn ++;
    if (playerTurn >= 1) {
        playerTurn = 0;
    }

  }

};
```

Comment: Without OP's source your guess is as best as mines on how her code is structured.

Comment: Okay I posted the whole thing now. It's not code written by me but rather a challenge on KhanAcademy where I'm currently learning javascript. There is a link there too. So in this case I'm only using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I solved it indirectly xD

What I did was change

```
Tile.prototype.onClick = function() {
    // If the tile is not empty, exit the function
    if (!this.empty ()) {
        exit();
    }
    // Put the player's symbol on the tile

        this.label = SYMBOLS[playerTurn];

    // Change the turn
    playerTurn ++;
    if (playerTurn >= 1) {
        playerTurn = 0;
    }
};
```

to

```
Tile.prototype.onClick = function() {
    // If the tile is not empty, exit the function
    if (this.empty ()) {
        // Put the player's symbol on the tile
        this.label = SYMBOLS[0];
        SYMBOLS.reverse();
    }
};
```

So instead of making an if-class for all the not-empty tiles that should do nothing and the rest is done ouside of the if-class, I made an if class for the empty tiles.

Yeah I know it was stupid but heyyy at least it's solved now.